# MVC download images from ftp and show in VIew

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Have some pictures on ftp location. My controller is getting list of paths for some specific images placed on ftp. What i want to do is to use those paths to download those pictures to local temporary folder and then show them inside gallery in view. Currently i am struggling with model to download those pictures but have some problems when trying to download pictures. Error posted below as well as current code. There is also folder creation code missing.

This is my controller method which would get paths list then calling download method to download pictures from ftp location to some temporary folder (and this temporary folder should be besides my application that then view could open images from that folder:

```
Function Details(Optional ByVal id As Long = Nothing) As ActionResult

        '--Temporary directory for pictures to be downloaded from ftp location (temp_dir) should be created besides application folders
        Dim temp_dir As String = "/temp_dir/"

        '--If not temp_dir exist ==> create this folder 
        '--if folder has been created properly go all next lines..

        '--Take list of all ftp paths e.g \someFolderForPictures\image1.jpg to be downloaded to temp_dir
        Dim PicsTrans As List(Of tblTransPics) = db.tblTransPics.Where(Function(f) f.IdTrans = id).ToList

        '--For each picture path download it to temp_dir folder with temporary name
        For Each imgFtpPath In PicsTrans
            Dim temp_picName As String = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
            DownloadFile(imgFtpPath.PicturePath, temp_dir & temp_picName)
        Next

        '-- If everythings went well - pass either temp_dir path to view and inside view those pictures will be opened or pass list of pictures (bytes)???
        Return View(temp_dir)
    End Function
```

Download file method:

```
Public Function DownloadFile(ByVal ftpPicLocation As String, destinationLocation As String) As Boolean
    Dim reqFTP As FtpWebRequest

    Try
        reqFTP = DirectCast(FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://someftpserver.com" & ftpPicLocation), FtpWebRequest)
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
        reqFTP.UseBinary = True
        reqFTP.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("myusername", "somepassword")

        Using outputStream As New FileStream(destinationLocation, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
            Using response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(reqFTP.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
                Using ftpStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                    Dim bufferSize As Integer = 2048
                    Dim readCount As Integer
                    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(bufferSize - 1) {}
                    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
                    While readCount > 0
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount)
                        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
                    End While
                End Using

            End Using
        End Using
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Failed to download", ex.InnerException)
    End Try
End Function
```

the error occurs on this line:

```
  Using outputStream As New FileStream(destinationLocation, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
```

and it says:

```
 Cannot find part of path „C:\temp_dir\f0f43089-4a16-4229-8ea6-2c3a55fde2ae”.
```

By the way how there could be C:\ ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove first slash in your temp_dir variable.

```
Dim temp_dir As String = "temp_dir/"
```

With this slash it means you want to write into your root. Your root equals C:\
By removing the first slash you get your temporary folder under the folder your application is running.

Comment: i changed but on same line now i receive: Cannot find part of path„C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\temp_dir\c4f563f1-6d5a-4f67-98eb-03a11ab57e92.jpg”.

Comment: ok i was able to do that - the resolution was to write like this: Dim temp_dir As String = Server.MapPath("~/temp_dir/")